# Django – Disabling ModelForm fields

Tags: django, django-forms

How is it possible to disable certain ModelForm fields to indicate that they're not editable? The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#disabled) seem to suggest setting the widget to `disabled` should do the trick, including making it tamper-resistent, however doing that form validation fails as the disabled fields POST as empty. (also trying to use the `has_changed` method, but doesn't seem to work for ModelForms and no equivalent is provided...)

I alternatively tried setting the `clean_<fieldname>` method on ModelForm level, to set the field to the referenced instance's value, but validation fails before that's reached.

Some sample code:

```py
# forms.py
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'slug': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'disabled': True
            })
        }


# views.py
def edit_mymodel(request, slug: str=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(MyModel, slug=slug)
    form_myform = MyForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form_myform.is_valid():
            # fails, because slug is empty in POST request
            pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    widgets = {
            'slug': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'readonly': True
            })
        }
```

disabled will make the input uneditable but will work as other fields, use readonly for this scenario

Comment: Works. But why?

Comment: because readonly fields will not te checked in the html validation